# Create clean vector layer without source

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

In Openlayers 3.9.0 I am implementing a code to draw features and grab their geometry type and coordinates.

I have use to OL2 when you could create a "clean" vector layer without a source, so the user could just create new features, without seeing the old, saved ones.

In OL3 I cannot create a vector layer without a source. I dont get any errors, but when I create a pint, I dont get it on the map, even though I set a style

```
layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    style:myStyle
});
```

In addition a vector layer must have a source, so I can do this

```
var features = sourceVector.getFeatures();
```

and get the newly created features.

Any solution to a clean vector layer without a source or at least without loading the saved features?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

just initialise your vector layer with an empty source like so:

```
layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source:new ol.source.Vector()
});
```

then to clean your layer from any features

```
var vecSource = layerVector.getSource();
var featsToRemove = vecSource.getFeatures();
    for (var f=0;f<featsToRemove.length;f++)
    {
    vecSource.removeFeature(featsToRemove[f]);
    }
```

or better as @Alvin Lindstam suggests

```
var vecSource = layerVector.getSource();
vecSource.clear()
```

I have not test it but it should work.

Comment: Tip: instead of looping through the features to remove them, consider using `vecSource.clear()`